"press enter to continue" in neovim
i was trying to add this keybinding to neovim to integrate with zellij:
-- running go tests
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>rt", function()
    return ":!zellij run -d Down -n go-tests -- go test " .. vim.fn.expand("%:p:h") .. "<CR>"
end, { expr = true, silent = true })

but when i hit enter and close zellij pane i see that annoying "press enter to continue", is there any way to prevent this? any keymap options or so?

vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rt', function()
  return ':silent !zellij run -d Down -n go-tests -- go test ' .. vim.fn.expand '%:p:h' .. '<CR>'
end, { expr = true, silent = true })

I think putting silent in front of the command will work

you're genius, thanks. didn't know you can use "silent" inside commands, it works
